# If function to check multiple column conditions across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm starting an Excel sheet collecting weekly data, and I'm trying to create an if statement to access the last(index) sheet in the workbook and check multiple conditions.

I need to check whether cells in column k are "true" and, if they are, whether the date in column J falls within the month range from the sheet called "Dashboard". If these two conditions are met, I'll add one to my counter and then ultimately print this counter number into a cell on the Dashboard sheet.

So far my code is:

```
Sub CreateTable()
Dim n As Integer, RangeCount As Integer
Dim MaxVal As Long

n = 0
RangeCount = 1
sheets(sheets.Count).Select) 'I don't want this line but I don't know how else to access the final sheet in code
MaxVal = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J1:J14")) 'Columns J and K will always be the same length
For RangeCount = 1 to MaxVal
    If Cells(RangeCount, 11) = "true" And Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Y17") <= sheets(sheets.Count).Select.Cells(RangeCount, 11) And sheets("Dashboard").WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("Y17", 0)) >= Cells(RangeCount, 11) Then
       n = n + 1
    End If
Next RangeCount
End Sub
```

Y17 is the cell in Dashboard where a month is listed (1/12/2022).
My current error is Object Required, but I think I've defined everything I need to define, etc. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try `sheets(sheets.Count).Cells(RangeCount, 11)` instead of `sheets(sheets.Count).Select.Cells(RangeCount, 11)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an issue with your conditons?

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateTable()
Dim n As Integer, RangeCount As Integer
Dim MaxVal As Long

n = 0
RangeCount = 1
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select                         'I don't want this line but I don't know how else to access the final sheet in code
MaxVal = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J1:J14"))  'Columns J and K will always be the same length
For RangeCount = 1 To MaxVal
    If CheckConditions(RangeCount) Then
       n = n + 1
    End If
Next RangeCount
End Sub


Function CheckConditions(locCnt As Integer) As Boolean    
Dim locTest As Boolean

'which worksheet? do you want the activesheet here?
locTest = Cells(locCnt, 11) = "true"  

locTest = locTest And Sheets("Dashboard").Range("Y17") <= Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(locCnt, 11)

'which worksheet for cells? do you want the activesheet here?
locTest = locTest And Sheets("Dashboard").WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("Y17", 0)) >= Cells(locCnt, 11)

CheckConditions = locTest
End Function
```

Comment: Hey, yea I didn't realise I didn't include my condition definitions in my code but they are there.
Why do you create a function specifically for this. Is it not possible for this to all be within the same sub? I'm appearing to have an issue with running the code with it as a function

Comment: There is no need to create a function for the condition check! It's just a question of readability! Why should there be an issue with running it as a function? Strange!